# show that $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} \geq \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}$ if $abc \geq 1 $

Tags: inequality

We want to show that $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} \geq  \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}$ if $abc \geq 1 $

I've tried to use AM-GM directly on the LHS but that obviously failed.

Simplifying the question gives $a^2b + b^2c + c^2a \geq ab + bc + ac$

The fact that this is $a(ab) + b(bc) + c(ca) \geq ab + bc + ac$ makes me think that there's a way to proceed from here, but I'm not quite sure how.

Note : a,b,c are real positive numbers

Comment: @Ak.how does $\frac{1}{b^2c} + \frac{1}{c^2a} + \frac{1}{a^2b} \geq \frac{1}{a^2bc} + \frac{1}{ab^2c} + \frac{1}{abc^2}$ solve the problem?

Comment: @Ak. but I got that inequality by simplifying the question, so that wouldn't work

Answer (score 2):

Case 1: Let $ab+bc+ca\ge a+b+c$, then the AM-HM of $a,b,c$ with weights as $1/b,1/c,1/a$ gives
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a} \ge \frac{1/a+1/b+1/c)^2}{1/(ab)+1/(bc)+1/ca)}=\frac{(ab+bc+ca)(1/a+1/b+1/c)}{a+b+c} \ge \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}.$$

Case 2: Let $(ab+bc+ca) \le a+b+c$, then AM-HM of $1/b,1/c,1/a$ with weights as $a,b,c$, we get
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+bc+ca} \ge ab+bc+ca=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{a}$$

Comment: what made you choose to view the relation between $ab + bc + ac$ and $a+b+c$ ?

Comment: Old experience!

Comment: one more thing, you referenced AM-HM with weights, but I'm not familiar with the existence of a weighted AM-HM inequality, could you reference a link or something with it?

Comment: Suppose $x,y,z$ are variables and $p,q,r$ are their frequencies (weights), them weighted AM is $AM=(px+qy+rz)/(p+q+r)$ and weighted $HM=\frac{p+q+r}{p/x+q/y+r/z}$ Then $AM \ge HM.$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a}
&\geq \frac{(abc)^{1/3}}{a} + \frac{(abc)^{1/3}}{b} + \frac{(abc)^{1/3}}{c}\\ 
&\geq \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}
\end{align}$$

The second inequality is obvious while the first one comes from Karamata's Majorization Inequality with the convexity of $f(x)=e^x$ and

$$\left(\ln\dfrac{(abc)^{1/3}}{c}, \ln\dfrac{(abc)^{1/3}}{b}, \ln\dfrac{(abc)^{1/3}}{a}\right) \prec   \left(\ln\dfrac{a}{b}, \ln\dfrac{b}{c}, \ln\dfrac{c}{a}\right)
$$

Let (WLOG) $\;\ln\dfrac{a}{b}\ge\ln\dfrac{b}{c}\ge\ln\dfrac{c}{a}$

We have $\;\dfrac{a}{b}\ge\dfrac{b}{c}\ge\dfrac{c}{a}$ thus, $\;ac\ge b^2\;$, $a^2\ge bc\;$ and $\;ab\ge c^2\;$ hence, we get $a\ge b$ and $a\ge c$ thus,

$$\dfrac{a}{b}\ge \dfrac{(abc)^{1/3}}{c} \implies \ln\dfrac{a}{b}\ge \ln\dfrac{(abc)^{1/3}}{c}$$
$$\dfrac{c}{a}\le \dfrac{(abc)^{1/3}}{a} \implies \ln\dfrac{c}{a}\le \ln\dfrac{(abc)^{1/3}}{a}$$

$$0=\ln\dfrac{(abc)^{1/3}}{c}+ \ln\dfrac{(abc)^{1/3}}{b}+ \ln\dfrac{(abc)^{1/3}}{a}=   
\ln\dfrac{a}{b}+ \ln\dfrac{b}{c}+ \ln\dfrac{c}{a}
$$

so that our majorization rule holds, hence first inequality holds.